# Eloquent: Api Resource - Can't retrieve an information from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently using `Laravel 5.6`, i want to create an user access control. I'm using three table : `user (id, username, email, password)`, `role (id, role, desc)` and a pivot table `role_user (user_id, role_id)`. My code is like below :

User Model

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Role Model :

```
/**
* Role Model
*/
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Api Resource :

```
/**
* Api Resource
*/
public function toArray($request)
{
   return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'username' => $this->username,
      'email' => $this->email,
      'role' => $this->whenPivotLoaded('role_user', function (){
          return $this->roles->name;
      })
      ];
   }
```

The problem is when i want to access the role information from pivot table, the role is dissappear and i got blank role information like this :

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "john",
        "email": "john.doe@mail.com",
    }
}
```

Could anyone here to help me to solve this problem?

**Thank You ~**

Comment: Could you share the controller code that returns the user?

Comment: @Quezler yes, of course. I just update my question

Answer (score 0):

Change `$this->roles->name;` to `return $this->roles->name;`

(don't be ashamed, took me a few minutes to notice it to )

Comment: oh, my bad. i'm forget to write `return` on this question and unfortunatelly the problem is still. i cant' get any information/access the pivot value

Comment: @Shinoda_ then try `User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id)->first()` ? (the pivot appears to need to load first)

Comment: the problem is still

Comment: and if you add `public $with = ['roles']` to the model class?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your controller function that is return this resource:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $id)->with('roles')->first();
```

and then `return new UserResource($user);`